# Multiple DNS for same server with multiple docker

Tags: docker, dns, port

First of all I am not very sure whether this question is to be asked here or not.
I have cretaed 3 docker containers (Web Application) for 3 different applications. All applications are running on PHP. I have specified 3 different ports for these 3 containers. currently all the applications are running fine like below -

```
Container 1 - http://Hostserver:8080
Container 2 - http://Hostserver:8181
Container 3 - http://Hostserver:8282
```

Is it possible to assign 3 different DNS for these 3 containers provided users should not be bothered about the port? For Example -

```
http://application1.testdomain.com should redirect to http://Hostserver:8080
http://application2.testdomain.com should redirect to http://Hostserver:8181
http://application3.testdomain.com should redirect to http://Hostserver:8282
```

In case it is possible, what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: This really depends on dns server, if your company could afford 3 hostname for your server in dns server, and all user in your company use this dns server, then it could be. For external internet, you have to buy 3 domain name for your server, if you can, you could also do it. Anyway, user need to use the dns server which include your server name. Of course, in a small environment, if you could ask user to modify `hosts` on his computer, then it also could be .

Comment: You will also need some sort of reverse proxy to route traffic from ports 80 and 443 to the per-container port.

Answer (score 0):

DNS assigns only to IP address. Therefore you can use NGINX reverse proxy for your case.

For example, you can refer to this how-to manual [How to Host Multiple Docker Containers on a Single Droplet with Nginx Reverse Proxy?](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-host-multiple-docker-containers-on-a-single-droplet-with-nginx-reverse-proxy)